# Meaning of "Autosettings" in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2, many product fields have been shuffled off to a group called "Autosettings".  Does anyone know why this section is named Autosettings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's called autosettings  because you can set some default values for these fields from `system->configuration->Catalog->Catalog->
Product Fields Auto-Generation`.
But in the latest version I don't see this section anymore.